# Combining array_agg and unnest

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-10, array

Given a dataset (with a `GIN` index on `values`):

```
key | values
-------------
 1  | {4,2,1}
 1  | {2,5}
 2  | {4,1,3}
```

I want to aggregate the arrays:

```
key | values
-------------
 1  | {4,2,1,5}
 2  | {4,1,3}
```

My first thought didn't work:

```
SELECT key, array_agg(DISTINCT unnest(values)) AS values FROM data GROUP BY key
```

> [0A000] ERROR: aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
>   Hint: You might be able to move the set-returning function into a LATERAL FROM item.

Not being familiar with `LATERAL FROM`, it's not obvious to me how to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to do the unnest in a sub-query:

```
select d."key", array_agg(distinct x.v) 
from data d
  cross join lateral unnest(d."values") as x(v)
group by d."key";
```

Set returning functions (like `unnest()`) should in general be used in the `from` part of a query. But to be able to reference a column from the table you need a [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL).

`from data cross join lateral unnest(...)` is an explicit way of writing `from data, unnest(...)` which also generates a cross join. But I prefer the explicit `cross join` operator to document that I indeed intended to write a cross join, rather than accidentally.

This will however not preserve the order of the elements.

Online example: https://rextester.com/TVIDB57711

Comment: @OrangeDog: you need the cross join (lateral actually) because otherwise you can't unnest to a sub-query (derived table). The `x()` is just a regular [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) that includes a column alias

Comment: @OrangeDog: `as v` does not provide a column alias it just happens to work because the table and column alias are the same then. Using an explicit column alias is cleaner code.

Comment: It appears that `LATERAL` isn't necessary - I get the same results and query plan both with and without it.

Comment: @OrangeDog: yes, it's optional when the (lateral) join is against a set returning function. I prefer to write it nevertheless  as [explained in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

Comment: It appears that other aggregates are going to give unexpected results with this join.

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT all_values) as uniq_values
FROM 
(SELECT key, 
        unnest(values) as all_values
FROM data) q1
GROUP BY key
```