# Multiple aggregates with cross (lateral) join

Tags: postgresql, join, aggregate, postgresql-10

Following on from [Combining array_agg and unnest](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/241989), given this data:

```
key |  a | b | c
------------------
 1  |  0 | 1 | {1,2}
 1  |  1 | 2 | {3}
 1  | -1 | 3 | {2}
 1  |  2 | 4 | {}
```

Executing this query:

```
SELECT 
  d.key,
  min(d.a) AS a,
  sum(d.b) AS b,
  array_agg(DISTINCT x.c) AS c 
FROM data AS d
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(d.c) AS x(c)
GROUP BY d.key
```

Gives the unexpected result:

```
key |  a | b | c
------------------
 1  | -1 | 7 | {1,2,3}
```

What's going on here, and how to get the correct sum?

---

#### Answer performance

On my actual data (16642 rows, 1942 keys, 6 aggregates), I get these cost estimates for each suggested solution.

- [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242107) option 1: `1761.12..49370.52`
- [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242107) option 2: `0.57..89214.72`
- [Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242111): `1761.12..49370.61`

Comment: The cost estimates are not really an indicator on the query performance. The actual runtime (generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` is the interesting thing - but this is the price you pay for not normalizing properly

Comment: The execution time for all three is around 300ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unnesting generates 2 rows for (key = 1, a = 0, b = 1), and the cross join removes the row with the empty array.

So your group by operates on the following set:

```
key | a  | b | c
----+----+---+--
  1 |  0 | 1 | 1
  1 |  0 | 1 | 2
  1 |  1 | 2 | 3
  1 | -1 | 3 | 2
```

One solution is to combine two group by queries, each one grouping n a different level:

```sql
select *
from (
  select d1."key", min(d1.a), sum(d1.b)
  from data d1
  group by d1."key"
) m
  join (
    select "key", array_agg(DISTINCT x.c) AS c 
    from data d2
      left join lateral unnest(d2.c) as x(c) on true
    where x.c is not null
    group by "key"
  ) a on a."key" = m."key";
```

Another approach is to only include the "first row" for each "unnested" group in the aggregates:

```sql
select d."key", 
       min(d.a) filter (where idx = 1 or idx is null), 
       sum(d.b) filter (where idx = 1 or idx is null),
       array_agg(distinct x.c)
from data AS d
  left join lateral unnest(d.c) with ordinality  AS x(c,idx) on true
group by d."key";
```

`with ordinality` returns the position of the unnested element in the original array. For the row with the empty array, that will be null.

Comment: I don't suppose there's any way to avoid repeating the filter for every other aggregate?

Comment: @OrangeDog: only if you use the first version

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your query is that the `CROSS JOIN` eliminates rows where `unnest()` produces no rows (happens for the empty array `{}`).

You could fix that with `LEFT JOIN .. ON true`, but the other problem is that rows are multiplied where `unnest()` returns multiple rows (happens for `{1,2}`).

Thats how you get `7` for the sum: `1 + 1 + 2 + 3`.

Joining two separate subqueries might be simplest / fastest:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT key, min(a) AS min_a, sum(b) AS sum_b
   FROM   data
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) x
JOIN  (
   SELECT key, array_agg(DISTINCT e) AS dist_c 
   FROM   data, unnest(c) e
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) y USING (key);
```

The plain join works because both subqueries have grouped by the same column - and as long as `key` is `NOT NULL`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e25b41963ad5ce7c534a7bc7630f0cf9)*

Related:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12464135/939860)